# OpenVPN bridged network without authentication

Tags: openvpn

I would like to configure *OpenVPN* multi-client server in bridged mode(`tap` virtual interface). My server-side configuration is following:

```
dev tap0
proto udp
port 1194
mode server
ifconfig-pool 10.10.1.97 10.10.1.98 255.255.255.192
management 127.0.0.1 1194
auth none
log-append /var/log/openvpn.log
verb 1
```

Now when I start the OpenVPN server I receive the `--mode server requires --tls-server` error message and server does not start. Is it mandatory to use TLS with multi-client bridged mode? For example it is possible to set up point-to-point L3(`tun` interface) VPN's without authentication and encryption.

Comment: Is that "without either authentication or encryption", or "without authentication but with encryption"? Your last clause is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, OpenVPN is a TLSv1 SSL Tunnel designed to create **secure point to point connections**, so if you didnt want authentication or encryption you would simply connect to the machines' public IP.

I have setup OpenVPN several times and when testing we use no authentication and self-signed SSL certificates. This is by far the easiest way to setup OpenVPN. If you setup your keychain with a revocation list, you can disable access to a client using the revocation list. [Here is some info](https://www.madboa.com/geek/openssl/#cert-self) you can use to generate the self-signed certificate...